# Why is my banner image collapsing in a100% div?

Tags: css

Tried to use slick banner lib this time around at the request of a client and my image seems to be collapsing inside of the div at 100% width and 500px height. I'm looking for it to re-scale @ a height of 500px. Have looked around and seem to be doing as recommended?

http://www.cucoders.com/

```
.slick-slide img
display: block;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: I'd use a CSS background image with a `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: @DBS - The image would not re-size with "background-size: cover;"

Comment: If the background is 100% width and a fixed height... it should resize, that's sort of the point of `cover`, it covers the available area.

Comment: @DBS - If you used a fixed height w/ cover, the image is not fully responsive and looks off from device to device. To solve for this issue we added:

background-position: 50% 0px;
overflow: hidden;

I disabled the above attributes on the first two slides and left it on the first @ the link below, if you want to see the results. Your answer was close, just missing two important lines of css to keep the image ration at 1:1

Solved @ http://cucoders.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get image fully responsive by using the code below. When just using background-image: cover; the image is not fully responsive and collapses on it's self. The below css works.

```
.background-image-3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url("http://www.cucoders.com/images/background.png");
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 background-position: 50% 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```